# Can "ld" add the rpaths automatically to an executable if it can find the needed dylibs at link time?

Tags: dynamic-library

The question is in the title, but anyway, let me explain it a bit more:

The most accepted way for correctly defining the ***install name*** for a dylib in MacOS is by making it relative to the `rpath`. For example:

```
otool -L ./LLVM/7.0.0/lib/libomp.dylib 
./LLVM/7.0.0/lib/libomp.dylib:   
   @rpath/libomp.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.50.2)
```

Here, `libomp.dylib` has `@rpath/libomp.dylib` as its ***install name***. So far so good.

The problem is when you create an executable linked to such a dylib. Even if you pass the correct `-L/path/to/libomp.dylib` flag at link time, so that `ld` can **successfully** link the executable, then you try to execute it, and obviously you get the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: mydumbexecutable
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

This of course can be fixed by using `install_name_tool` on either the dylib (changing its ***install name*** so that it doesn't depend on the `rpath`, and linking the executable again, but this is not considered good practice), or, the recommended way, to use `install_name_tool` on the executable, adding to it the proper `rpath` so that the dylib can be found.

But... just wondering... isn't there a flag in `ld` that automatically adds the `rpath` for you? I mean, if `ld` is able to link the executable because it **did** find the dylibs, why cannot automatically store the proper `rpath` in the executable?

I understand this should be optional behaviour, as sometimes you prefer to define the `rpaths` yourself, but... a flag for doing it automatically would make my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: no, it cannot.

Your question sounds a lot like an XY problem, so first I would recommend going back and reexamine if this really is your main problem, or there's some higher level problem that is actually the problem, you're trying to solve.

First off, I would note that you do not have to use `install_name_tool` to set these values after the fact. You can set these while compiling the library and the program. If you're using clang/gcc, you can use the `-install_name` option. Similar exists for other compilers.

The reason that ld doesn't automatically add rpaths according to where it found the dylibs is that this would in general produce a binary that runs on your machine, and your machine only. I.e. it is tailored for your specific installation. This is normally not what you want. You want to produce a binary that others can take and run on their computers.

If you're making a "standard project" (i.e. like from an Xcode template) with shared libraries, you won't have to fiddle with rpaths or install names. I.e. usually you have the shared libraries placed at standard locations that are search by the dynamic linker by standard, so that you won't have to define anything special.

However, it seems you're wanting to create something very customized for your usage. If you really want to specify that the dylib is at a specific place (because you only want to run it on your own computer, or computers set up like yours) - you can do so by simply specifying an absolute path for it.

If you want to create something that can easily be copied to other computers without needing seperate installation of dylibs, you often want to bundle your dylib with the application itself. Then you can use a path relative to the executable by using `@executable_path` instead of `@rpath`.

In my view @rpath is most helpful when you have multiple applications that are "loosely connected" that you would like to share a library that you do not want to place in a system-wide standard location.

Comment: Yes, I do believe I'm somehow doing things in a way different to the way I would be supposed to follow. But then, how are you supposed to link an executable to a locally installed library that has rpath in its install name? It seems you cannot link to locally installed libs unless you run install_name_tool on your executable, and that's what I wished to avoid...

Comment: First off, as I wrote in the answer you never have to run "install_name_tool" - you can just use the "-install_name" option for your compiler. However - the first part of your question seems to me to imply that you have kind of "got lost" in this, and you're not really trying to do something with "rpath" on purpose. You say that you have a local library with rpath in its install name - I suppose this is the libomp.dylib that you detail in your question? - Did you by chance compile and install that yourself? - You then shouldn't have used rpath when compiling it.

Comment: I.e. in other words - if you do things "normally" you wouldn't end up with "@rpath" in the install name of the library. If you just install libomp like any normal user would do (i.e. "brew install libomp") then "otool -L libomp.dylib" gives you "/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib" ... not something with @rpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jksoegaard. Yes, I'm talking about software (libraries and apps) I build from source and install in a local tree within the user's home directory. Regarding libomp, I built it together with LLVM, and I didn't change the default settings for rpath because I assumed the defaults would be fine for local installation, but now I realise it's not the case. But I found this problem in many other cases, like Qt for example. I guess all projects built with CMake choose to use rpath by default. And maybe configure-based ones too.

Comment: Nope, not really.

Comment: I'll need to check better, because most libraries I install in a local directory do have `@rpath` in their install names. And it happens without modifying the default build settings (except for specifying my own install prefix: the local directory). Of course if I build libs static, this doesn't happen, but I'd like to use dynamic libs. From your comments I guess that either nobody is installing dynamic libraries in a local directory, or I'm changing something without realizing.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just pass `-rpath path_to_add` in the linker flags to clang. If you're building something for your box only, this is makes your executable work, if that's what's important to you.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I meant automatically adding the rpath for you. The thing is, `ld` is able to link because I passed the library paths as `-L` flags, so, technically, it should be able to add any stuff needed for the executable to run, without you specifying rpaths manually.